# How to move a Wordpress installation to a subdirectory

Tags: directory, installation

I want to replace my WordPress site with a non-WordPress site but keep the original WordPress site in a sub-directory.  I have read through and tried [this](https://wordpress.org/support/article/giving-wordpress-its-own-directory/) and [various](https://manage.accuwebhosting.com/knowledgebase/1269/How-do-I-change-document-root-folder-to-some-sub-folder-using-an--htaccess-file.html) [other methods](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/move-wordpress-root-subfolder-52605.html) but none seem to work or don't seem to fit my needs.

The current WordPress installation: https://example.com

I want it at: https://example.com/blog

Importantly all the instructions ask me to copy the index.php and .htaccess files to the root at the end.  This I don't want.  In the root, I will have a different index.php that is unrelated to WordPress.

Any help appreciated. TIA

Comment: those are talking about moving the WordPress folder as in the code, but keeping the site at the same URL. What you're talking about however is a site migration. Articles talking about moving from `abc.com` to `xyz.com` are what you want to look for

Comment: Move the entire WordPress installation (including index.php and .htaccess) to the blog directory. Change the Site URL and WordPress URL manually in the database. (You may also need to change a few other instances of main url to blog url in database)

Answer (score 0):

Move all your WP installation to the subdirectory, Then uodate in your DB (wp_options by default) the `siteurl` and `home` with the new url.
change https://example.com to https://example.com/blog

You need also to replace all ocurrences of example.com to example.com/blog in your DB manually, with SQL or with a plugin such **Better Search Replace**